# /oracle is 91% what to delete?

Tags: oracle, linux

```
 /dev/xvdf             109G   93G   11G  91% /oracle
```

My `/Oracle` diskspace is now 91% full. I have deleted some temp files already. Whatelse can I delete here in this directory? Thanks for helping.

```
/dev/xvdf             109G   94G  9.5G  91% /oracle
/dev/xvdg              60G   46G   11G  81% /orabackup
[oracle@bsc-ol ~]$ cd /oracle
[oracle@bsc-ol oracle]$ ls
apache-tomcat-8.0.26  ftpusers       lms-online-cel     lms-online-sp   tempf
app                   Installers     lms-online-demo    lms-online-tgh
data                  lms-online     lms-online-hacaca  lost+found
exported              lms-online-3r  lms-online-lhyk    oraInventory
[oracle@bsc-ol oracle]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a recent (>11.2) release of Oracle, my bet is the diag destination usually located in `$ORACLE_BASE/diag`.

Database logs are kept in the `rdbms/$DATABASE/$INSTANCE` directories, listener logs in `tnslsnr/$HOST/$LISTENER`directories.

You purge the XML files with `adrci`command. Be aware that this command does not purge the text logs in the `trace` subdirectory. You need the purge/truncate these logs via normal OS housekeeping procedures, e.g. logrotate.

Other possibilities are trace files, backups or exports in the $ORACLE_HOME/dbs directory, but these should easily reveal themselves.